# enabling multiple instances of mongodb on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

I am working on a SaaS application where there will be a separate database for each tenant and one landlord/master database for the landlord. So
`foo.example.com` will connect the `sales_foo` database
`bar.example.com` will connect the `sales_bar` database and so on.

Now I have two environments, **staging** and **testing** both on the same server managed by a virtual host. So the problem is if I have 10 tenants then there will be 10 databases plus one landlord database. These all databases should be in one environment and one environment should not access other environment's databases. How can I achieve this?

Till now I have created separate .conf file for each environment and I can start mongod process with that conf as well. But how can I keep it enable all the time? Is it possible?

On a side note, I am using laravel for interacting with database.

Comment: On mongodb each databases ve his own users, so u neednt to open another mongodb on another port, just use on different databases

Comment: @LuisBote But then how will the test and staging environment will have a separate database. Eg. the foo tenant on the stagging server should access the sales_foo database on stagging and the foo tenant on testing server should access the sales_foo database on testing.

Comment: Use sales_foo and sales_foo_testing, i, ve .json where my code find database, and i use production database or test